# Excel VBA/C# Subtotal Function: What does TotalList parameter do?

Tags: c#, excel, vba, excel-interop, subtotal

I'm trying to get the subtotals for a table in C# using Microsoft.Interop.Excel, and there is a built in function for that.

[Here][1] is the link to the documentation for the Subtotal function.

I understand what GroupBy and Function parameters do, but what exactly is the TotalList parameter for? Microsoft describes it as:

"An array of 1-based field offsets, indicating the fields to which the subtotals are added."

How are these offsets being read? In pairs for row and column offset? In examples I see whole arrays of many numbers being used for this. How do I make use of this?
[1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.subtotal?view=excel-pia

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.subtotal has an example - I would guess it represents the column number(s) in the range to which totals should be applied

Comment: Eg: (in VBA)  `Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Subtotal GroupBy:=1, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(3, 5)` would group a table of data starting in A1, according to the first column, and add subtotals in the third and fifth columns.

Comment: @TimWilliams That was my suspicion as well. But if it is the column offset, why are we able to put in an array of many numbers? That is what has me confused.

Comment: You put in as many numbers as you have columns for which you want subtotals calculated for.  If you only have one column to subtotal, you can just pass in a single number in place of an array (at least, in VBA that works)

Comment: @TimWilliams I think that's it! Please post it as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass an array of as many numbers as you have columns for which you want subtotals calculated. If you only have one column to subtotal, you can just pass in a single number in place of an array (at least, in VBA that works)

Eg: (in VBA) -

`Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Subtotal GroupBy:=1, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(3, 5)`

would group a table of data starting in A1, according to the first column, and add subtotals in the third and fifth columns.